# ¿Cómo bloqueo el doble envío de petición ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hola comunidad stackoverflow.

Estoy teniendo problemas con el bloqueo de doble evío de petición de ajax, tengo una pantalla con una tabla JSGrid, por cada fila me muestra los detalles de cada registro en un modal, en éste mismo ejecuto una petición que me muestra una lista de elementos(Menú padre) desde un SP, en ésta misma petición anido otro ajax que me ejecuta otra acción que muestra una lista de submenus tomando como parámetro de entrada el menú padre.

Uno de los problemas es, que por cada que doy clic a una fila vuelve a anidar los menús padres en el modal, o sea que si doy clic 3 veces, los agrega 3 veces, solo los necesito una vez, con la segunda petición éstoy teniendo problemas en la parte de mostrar los submenus, ya que me los muestra dentro del contenido del primer elemento(menú padre) y no dentro del contenido de cada menú padre, utilizo un ciclo for por cada petición, ya que necesito todos los menús padres que existan, y de cada menú todos los submenus que pertenecen a éste.

Soy nueva en stackoverflow, y estaré agradecida si pueden ayudarme o darme alguna idea de qué mas hacer, ya no encuentro más información que pueda ayudarme.

Les comparto mi codigo.

Esta es mi función del dialogo

```
             var showDetailsDialog = function (dialogType, empleado) 
             {
             menus(); //el nombre de mi función en la que anido otra petición, por cada que doy clic a un row me vuelve a anidar los radiobuttons, es decir se repite la petición dentro del modal
             }
```

Función del rowclick de mi jsgrid

```
            rowClick: function (args) 
            {
            //dialogo con los argumentos del registro seleccionado
            showDetailsDialog("Información del", args.item);
            },
```

Función Menu

```
    function menus() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: 'Lista_fathers?bandera=Menu',
        success: function (result) {
            for (var i in result) {
                $('#listaMenu').append('<div id = "grupoMenu"><input type="radio" id="MenuNombre" name="menufathers" value = "' + result[i].MenuFather + '" >' + result[i].MenuFather + '</input><span id="flechita" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" onclick="ocultarmostrar()")></span><br/><div id="contenido"></div></div>');
                valormenu = result[i].MenuFather;
                pruebaSubmenus(valormenu); //función con petición para conseguir los submenus
            }
            return resultado;
        }
    });
};
```

Función submenus

```
   function pruebaSubmenus(menufather) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: 'Lista_menus?menu=' + menufather,
        success: function (result2) {
            var resultado1 = "";
            for (var i in result2) {
                if (result2.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    $('#contenido').append('<label>' + result2[i].NombreMenu + '</label><br/>');
                }
            }

            $('#contenido').hide();
            return resultado1;
        }
    });
};
```

Saludos y gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Nosotros tampoco tenemos información para poder ayudarte, si no [editas tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/128316/edit) poniendo el fragmento de código donde se está presentando el problema.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow en español, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ademas tienes que ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Comment: Gracias A.Cedano, ya edité mi pregunta.

Comment: Gracias Luis Fernando, lo tomaré en cuenta.

Comment: Una pregunta, si lo ejecutas una vez, ya no necesitas ejecutarlo más veces, seguro?

Comment: Y si usas una variable como banderita (seteado como 0 al comienzo), de forma que cuando muestre tooooodo tu menú al terminar le cambie el valor a la variable banderita (a 1 u otra cosa), de forma que si es distinto a 0 ya no haga todo el proceso de mostrar?

Comment: Así es, solo necesito que se ejecute una vez, ya que mi modal es informativo, o sea, el modal me muestra los datos del row seleccionado, pero eso lo realicé en el modal antes de llamar la función menus(), lo que necesito es que me muestre todos los menus y submenus una sola vez, ya que serán los mismos aunque se cambie de row.

Comment: Gracias KuroNeko, si utilizo banderas dentro de mi controlador, mis banderas son "Menu", y "SubMenu",  como lo comenté ya me muestra mis datos esperados, el problema es que me los muestra cada que doy clic, y los submenus solo los muestra en el primer contenido del primer menú, no en el contenido de cada menu.
MyTable = FunctionUsuariosCedis.FunctionListaAccesos.FunctionLista("Menu", menu); 
                MyTable = FunctionUsuariosCedis.FunctionListaAccesos.FunctionLista("SubMenu", menu);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que con lo que te pongo debajo debería valer. Básicamente creo una variable con la que controlo si se hizo click.

```
var hiceClick = false;


function menus() {
   //así sólo ejecutarás el código ajax si la variable hiceClick es false
   if(!hiceClick)
   {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: 'Lista_fathers?bandera=Menu',
        success: function (result) {
            //Aquí informas la variable para asegurar que ya se hizo click
            hiceClick=true;
            for (var i in result) {
                $('#listaMenu').append('<div id = "grupoMenu"><input type="radio" id="MenuNombre" name="menufathers" value = "' + result[i].MenuFather + '" >' + result[i].MenuFather + '</input><span id="flechita" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" onclick="ocultarmostrar()")></span><br/><div id="contenido"></div></div>');
                valormenu = result[i].MenuFather;
                pruebaSubmenus(valormenu); //función con petición para conseguir los submenus
            }
            return resultado;
        }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Me sirvió para mi primer problema, te lo agradezco demasiado. Saludos.

Comment: si finalmente fue la solución, márcala como solucionada, y vótala si te fue útil!!  Gracias a tí por entrar al foro!! y encantado de ayudar!!! salu2!!